# why my scanf doesn't work right and when i move it, it works fine?

Tags: c, input, scanf

I want to write a simple calculator in C but when I run this code it just gets my numbers and doesn't get my operator and goes out from the running window! and when I move my scanf operator to top of the other scanf, it works right! why?!!!!

```
float num1, num2;

char op;
scanf("%f", &num1);
scanf("%f", &num2);
scanf("%c", &op);

switch(op)
{
    case '+':
    printf("%f + %f = %f", num1, num2, num1 + num2);
    break;
    case '-':
    printf("%f - %f = %f", num1, num2, num1 - num2);
    break;
    case '*':
    printf("%f * %f = %f", num1, num2, num1 * num2);
    break;
    case '/':
    printf("%f / %f = %f", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
    break;

    default :
    printf("error");
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Insert a blank before % as  scanf(" %c", &op);

Comment: If not already done elsewhere printing a \n new-line will help.

Comment: It is very informative to **print the offending character** in the `default:` case.

Comment: What is the difference between the way the conversion specifier `"%c"` behaves and how `"%f"` behaves? What does one do that the other does not? In fact what is it that `"%c"` and `"%[..]"` do not do that all other conversion specifiers do?

Answer (score 2):

The format string in this call

```
scanf("%c", &op);
```

is used to read all characters including white space characters from the input buffer. So after you entered the last number this call read the new line character `'\n'`.

Instead use

```
scanf(" %c", &op);
      ^^^
```

This allows to skip white space characters in the input buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if it takes white space as my operator so why it didn't run default ?!

Comment: @ermia.l I have not understood what you mean/ The space in the beginning of the format string allows to skip for example the new line character '\n' that appears the input  buffer when you press the Enter key.